# Raise top border line of tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have designed a tab bar which looks like so...

[image]

But I want to raise the top border of the tab bar so that the centre big image comes down within the border. It should look like so...
[image]

How can I achieve this...?

Comment: This solved the answer @T. Wei..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this code to remove the top border of UITabbar.

```
UITabBar.appearance().layer.borderWidth = 0.0
UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()mage = UIImage()
```

Comment: The problem could be fixed by the suggestion of @T. Wei...

Comment: Also @AtulParmar, I don't want to delete the top border but raise it. And that problem could be fixed

Comment: Okay dear, No an issue, this code will remove the top border